# Search object for a word and return results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have basic object and I want to search the title and description values and return the found objects. After your help, I can output them in HTML. I currently get a syntax error.

In the example I want to return all objects that contain the search term "dog"

```js
var search_term = "dog";
var search_results = [];
var page_json = [{
  "page_title": "Display",
  "page_url": "/display/",
  "page_description": "We display stuff. search this description for the word dog.",
}, {
  "page_title": "DRAM",
  "page_url": "/dram/",
  "page_description": "stuff about dram here",
}, {
  "page_title": "TVs",
  "page_url": "/tv/",
  "page_description": "stuff about tvs here",
},];

$(page_json).each(function(i, value) {
  //console.log( value.page_description );
  // search for our term in the description AND title values
  if ($(value.page_description).contains(search_term)) {
    console.log(value);
    // put that object into search_results array
  }
});
```

The answer I went with...

```
var search_term = "dog";
var search_results = [];
var page_json = [{
        "page_title": "Display",
        "page_url": "/display/",
        "page_description": "search this description for the word dog.",
    },{
        "page_title": "this title has a dog",
        "page_url": "/dram/",
        "page_description": "stuff about dram here",
    },{
        "page_title": "TVs",
        "page_url": "/tv/",
        "page_description": "stuff about tvs here",
    },
];

var search = function(search_term) {
    return page_json.filter(function(item) {
        // if search term is inside the title OR description
        if (item.page_description.indexOf(search_term) !== -1 || item.page_title.indexOf(search_term) !== -1){
            return item;
        }
    })
}

search_results = search(search_term);

console.log(search_results);
```

Comment: Note that what you have is an object, not JSON. I have edited the question as such

Comment: Usually I use https://underscorejs.org/ for these kind of actions .Give it a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need use Jquery here.
Javascript have the filter function, which fits very well for this situation.

```
var search_term = "dog";
var search_results = [];
var page_json = [{
    "page_title": "Display",
    "page_url": "/display/",
    "page_description": "We display stuff. search this description for the word dog.",
},
{
    "page_title": "DRAM",
    "page_url": "/dram/",
    "page_description": "stuff about dram here",
},
{
    "page_title": "TVs",
    "page_url": "/tv/",
    "page_description": "stuff about tvs here",
},
];

search = function(search_term, json) {
    return json.filter(function(i) {
        if (i.page_description.indexOf('about') !== -1) return i;
    })
}

search_results = search(search_term, page_json);

console.log(search_results);
```

Comment: Cool. How do you search the page title along with the description too?

Comment: Nvm I got it thanks!.

`if (item.page_description.indexOf(search_term) !== -1 || item.page_title.indexOf(search_term) !== -1){
            return item;
        }`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how this's done with jquery, but here's how you'd do it in JS:

```
const foundObject = page_json.find(obj=> 
     obj.page_title.includes(search_term) ||
     obj.page_description.includes(search_term)
   )
```

`console.log(foundObject)` returns the desired output.

If you want to do it with a plain for loop:

```
 let foundObject=null;
 for(let i=0; i < page_json.length; i++){
   const exists = page_json[i].page_title === search_term || page_json[i].page_description === search_term;
   if(exists) {
      foundObject = page_json[i]; // What you want.
   }
 }
if(foundObject) { // Do something.. }
```

Let me know if that isn't clear!

Answer (score 0):

For searching for the correct page_title you'd put the following:

```
if(page_json[i]["page_title"] == 'whatever title' && page_json[i]["page_description"] == 'whatever description'){
//do something here
}
```

or

```
  if(page_json[i]["page_title"] == 'whatever title'){ 
   //do something
  }
    if (page_json[i]["page_description"] == 'whatever description'){
    //do something here
    }
```

Comment: If you do `page_json[i]["page_title"] = 'whatever title'` that is NOT a comparison but an assignment. Please reconsider your answer.

Comment: I was already editing it while you were typing that out lol, thank you though

Comment: Nice! I'd still recommend you using a strict comparison(e.g. `===` instead of `==`) with primitive values, if you'd compare variables together.  
In addition, for a search feature, I don't think you can use imperative comparison. Like `page_json[i]["page_title"] === 'whatever title'`. That's because this won't return `true` until the user writes `whatever title` literally. Which is not what you want! See my answer above. However, you answer would perfectly work for variables comparison otherwise.